# given budget and grant find the maximum cap value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The awards committee had planned to give n research grants this year, out of a its total yearly budget. However, the budget was reduced to b dollars. The committee members has decided to affect the minimal number of highest grants, by applying a maximum cap c on all grants: every grant that was planned to be higher than c will now be c dollars. Help the committee to choose the right value of c that would make the total sum of grants equal to the new budget.

I am not able understand this problem it was asked in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with a problem like that, you have to take it one step at a time. Also, if you are having trouble understanding what's required, ask the interviewer for clarification. Many times, the question will be purposely vague so that the interviewer can see how you go about defining a problem before trying to solve it. Part of your job as an application developer will be to gather clear and complete requirements before starting the task of building an application.

You have `b` dollars to work with, and you want to fund the highest value grants that were previously approved, but at no more than `c` dollars each. Apparently, grants less than `c` dollars are automatically approved, provided there is money left in the budget.

First, sort the previously approved grants by dollar amount, descending. That is, the highest value grant will be at the front of the list. This way, you approve as many of the highest value grants as possible.

Then, go through the list, starting at the front, and approve grants, capping the amount to no more than `c` dollars. If the adjusted amount is less than or equal to the remaining budget, approve that grant.

In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
grants = all grants sorted by amount, in descending order
remaining_budget = b

for each grant in grants
    amount = grant.amount

    // cap the grant amount to no more than c
    if amount > c then
        amount = c

    if amount > remaining_budget then
        // grant not approved
    else
        // approve grant
        remaining_budget = remaining_budget - amount
end for
```

Comment: @AnukuL`c` is a constant: the maximum amount for any grant. See OP's description, and mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {

static double findGrantsCap(double[] grantsArray, double newBudget) {
    int n = grantsArray.length;
    Arrays.sort(grantsArray); // sort array first
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += grantsArray[i]; // if sum is less than newBudget return
    }

    if (sum < newBudget)
        return grantsArray[n - 1]; // return max grant that is last array index value.

    double cap = newBudget / n; // gives avg cap = 38
    double budget = newBudget;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (cap < grantsArray[i - 1])
            return cap;
        budget = budget - grantsArray[i - 1]; // 190 = 190 - 2
        cap = budget / (n - i); // . cap = 188-4 = 47
    }
    return cap;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution s1 = new Solution();
    double arr[] = {2, 100, 50, 120, 1000};
    double budget = 190;
    double result = s1.findGrantsCap(arr, budget);
    System.out.println(" Cap is "+result);
  }
}

/*
Output
Cap is 47.0
*/
```